call function uniswapv2 swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens return UniswapV2: INVALID_TO
i call the following function in js :
    function swapForShare(uint amountOut) public {
        uint ethBalanceBefore = address(this).balance;
        require(ethBalanceBefore > 0, "Contract has no ETH balance");
        console.log("ethBalanceBefore", ethBalanceBefore);
        uint ethAmountToSwap = ethBalanceBefore / 10;
        require(ethAmountToSwap > 0, "ETH amount to swap is zero");
        console.log("ethAmountToSwap", ethAmountToSwap);

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = WETH;
        path[1] = address(this);

        uint256 initialBalance = balanceOf(address(this));

        // Perform the swap
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{
            value: ethAmountToSwap
        }(0, path, address(this), block.timestamp);

        uint256 finalBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        console.log(address(this), msg.sender);
        console.log("Amounts received:", initialBalance, finalBalance);
    }


but return the following error
  Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'UniswapV2: INVALID_TO'

when the value of the address(this) change to the msg.sender value it works as expected but i need to swap the ETH and save in the token address
thanks in advance
